# how to download file telegram bot?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I use bot API v15.0.0.0 and downloaded file(Photo,Document,Audio,etc.) from user with this code, but when I run, file not open and file size is 0 KB.

```
var message = update.Message;

else if (message.Type == MessageType.Photo) {

  var file = bot.GetFileAsync(message.Photo.LastOrDefault().FileId);
  var fileName = file.Result.FileId + "." + file.Result.FilePath.Split('.').Last();

  using(var saveImageStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)) 
  {
     bot.DownloadFileAsync(file.Result.FilePath, saveImageStream);
  }
  bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Image save");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `saveImageStream` is being disposed before the async `DownloadFileAsync` has had time to write to the stream.

The code should await async function calls and avoid making blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait()`

```
//...

var file = await bot.GetFileAsync(message.Photo.LastOrDefault().FileId);
var fileName = file.FileId + "." + file.FilePath.Split('.').Last();

using(var saveImageStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)) {
    await file.FileStream.CopyToAsync(saveImageStream);
}
await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Image save");

//...
```

Take some time and review the [Bot Code Examples](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples)

https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/tree/master/src/Telegram.Bot